# page.setCookie as no affect when using Puppeteer on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am having a strange issue with Puppeteer. Current cookie setting code as follows:

(Save cookie)

```
const cookies = await page.cookies();
await checkMongoConnection();
account.cookies = JSON.stringify(cookies, null, null);
await account.save();
await closeMongoConnection();
```

(Load Cookie)

```
const options = {
    headless: true,
    defaultViewport: { width: 1366, height: 768 },
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: [
        '--disable-sync',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors'
    ],
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation']
};

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);
const page = await browser.newPage();
// Cookies
if (account.cookies) {
    // I have checked this with console.log it does contain cookies
    const cookies = JSON.parse(account.cookies);
    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
}

await page.goto('https://www.some-website.com');
```

This works without any issues when run on macOS (both with `headless` set to `false` and `true`), also note I am using Chromium.

However when I try to run this setup on my Linux Ubuntu server just setting the cookie has no affect. Has anyone else come across this issue before? Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

When I log the cookies I get from the database I get something like:

```
[
  {
    name: 'personalization_id',
    value: '"v1_FijCjdT7iRj3K+cbhPiPIg=="',
    domain: '.somedomain.com',
    path: '/',
    expires: 1664967308.337118,
    size: 47,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: true,
    session: false,
    sameSite: 'None'
  }, ....
```

I have tried logging the cookies after they are set:

```
// Cookies
if (account.cookies) {
    const cookies = JSON.parse(account.cookies);
    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
}

console.log('check cookies');
const newCookies = await page.cookies();
console.log(newCookies);
```

This just results in an empty array `[]`, so it seems they are refusing to set.

Comment: Have you tried to narrow down the issue? Does `account.cookies` actually contain any cookies?

Comment: I did check `account.cookies` and it does contain the cookies

Comment: Did you run it with a window and check the dev tools for the cookies?

Comment: Updated the question a little. I have logged the pages cookies after they are set and it's just an empty array `[]`